# django2.0 forms.ValidationError always return me 'password_mismatch'!

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to valid email isn't exists, so I do this

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(auth_forms.UserCreationForm):
    code = forms.CharField(label=_('valid code'), max_length=6)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = cleaned_data['email']
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('email already in use'), code='invalid')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'code')
```

and I want, when user register, if email is exists, I will return "email already in user" to him, now I just print it, when forms is invalid, so I do this in `views.py`

**views.py**

```
class RegisterView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    extra_context = {'page': 'register'}
    success_url = '/'
    success_message = _('register success')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.error_messages)
        error_msg = list(form.error_messages.values())[0]
        return utils.ajax_error(error_msg)
```

but, when I run it, I give some data to form, is all valid exists `email`
I should get `email aliready in use`, but I always get `{'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match."}`
but the `password1` and `password2` is same!
Why I always get the error about password !

Comment: to check for email validation you can set email field to unique, it will always raise integrity error if any duplicate email field found

Comment: @Gahan  I dont want to fix it in this way, I just want to know WHY？ and how can I get the right error

Comment: If you set your model field to an `EmailField` with `unique=True`, then you will get an error displayed to use an email that hasn't been used yet and a correct email address.